# meteor simpl-schema attachSchema crashes in package

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

When using simpl-schema, collection2 and autoform in a package I get the following error building the application.

```
W20170317-16:16:33.466(8)? (STDERR) Error: _constructorOptions key is missing "type"
W20170317-16:16:33.466(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/.../jointtest/node_modules/simpl-schema/dist/SimpleSchema.js:858:26
W20170317-16:16:33.466(8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/.../jointtest/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:158:9)
```

The main program has no problems and attaches the schema to the collection.

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import { Collection2 } from 'meteor/aldeed:collection2-core';
import { AutoForm } from 'meteor/aldeed:autoform';

import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);
SimpleSchema.debug = true;

import './main.html';

export const TheElements = new Mongo.Collection("theElements");
export const ThePoolSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: String
});
TheElements.attachSchema(ThePoolSchema);
```

The package looks as follows:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

import { Collection2 } from 'meteor/aldeed:collection2-core';
import { AutoForm } from 'meteor/aldeed:autoform';

import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);
SimpleSchema.debug = true;

export const Elements = new Mongo.Collection("elements");    
export const PoolSchema = new SimpleSchema({
        name: String
});
Elements.attachSchema(PoolSchema); // Error on this statement
```

package.js:

```
Npm.depends({
        'simpl-schema': '0.2.3',
        jointjs: '1.0.3',
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.4.3.2');
  api.use([
        'blaze-html-templates',
        'ecmascript',
        'session',
        'twbs:bootstrap@3.3.6',
        'aldeed:autoform@6.0.0',
        'momentjs:moment@2.10.6',
        'aldeed:collection2-core@2.0.0'
  ]);
  api.mainModule('af-test.js');
});
```

I probably do something wrong but ran out of ideas ...

Answer (score 1):

```
export const PoolSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: String
```

});

The property `name` should be `type`.